# How can I change text color in legend?

Tags: gnuplot

How can I change the font color of each legend entry?
I would like to have for each legend entry the same color for key text and line type.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`set key textcolor variable`

Example below
[image]

Comment: So easy. Nice! Thx.